# Magento2 What is the earning ratio of paid extension on Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

Magento2 What is the earning ratio of paid extension on Magento Marketplace? I have created an extension & want to sell on marketplace how will I get the Money to my account when user purchases an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will receive 70% of revenue, the other 30% is earned by Magento itself.

You can have a detailled look here: https://devdocs.magento.com/marketplace/sellers/sales.html

There 's another useful document that is related to  all the Magento marketplace topics you are searching for. You will find all the other answers in this document:
https://developer.magento.com/?_ga=2.252411145.1619178013.1627371862-1760574006.1627371862.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

They updated the deal and now is a 85% / 15%